# Rotativa doesn't executes jquery scripts in views correctly

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, rotativa

I'm using **Rotativa** to generate a view as PDF and it generates correctly.

However some of the html elements such as `div` have a border and the problem here is that I see it cut in half of that place in the first page of PDF and half of that placed in the second page in bad view.

Also I can't execute jquery scripts in this view (to handle my problem), when I run that view in general (without using **`ViewAsPdf`**) my scripts work fine, but with using **`ViewAsPdf`** it doesn't work.

I've checked out this question as a prior research:
[Rotativa ViewAsPdf not executing jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47834906/rotativa-viewaspdf-not-executing-jquery)

```
var z = parseInt(res);   
$(".softwares-info-block[data-val-id=" + z + "]").addClass("margin-top-box"); 
// it doesn't work (works fine without using rotativa)

$(".softwares-info-block[data-val-id = 10 ]").addClass("margin-top-box"); 
// it works fine (works fine when using rotativa, tried this in manually to check my scripts)
```

**Edit:**
[Here's a snapshot of the problem](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1N2nobTCegc8D__6cPBIixJ3GPWtOuoLr)

Comment: I think you need to post some images showing how it should look and how it does look, and potentially the HTML.

Comment: I add a picture link of my problem , thanks to remind me

Comment: Any luck with this?